# Netlify pretty query

Tags: web, url-rewriting, netlify

I want to host a Netlify website where you can search for specific users. Currently its like this https://example.com/users?q=exampleuser . (its https://example.com/users.html but pretty url'ed)

But what I want is to make the URL query pretty. So the endresult should be https://example.com/users/exampleuser but it should still be a url query so the JavaScript can make calls based on the query.

e.g.:

- https://example.com/users?q=test123 to
  https://example.com/users/test123
- https://example.com/users?q=example456 to
  https://example.com/users/example456

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule will work with:

```
/users q=:q /users/:q 200
```

When you navigate to `https://example.com/users?q=exampleuser`, you must have an existing endpoint at `https://example.com/users/exampleuser/` or it will give a 404 status code, but will still rewrite the original path.

***Note:*** If you have an existing endpoint at `/users/` this method will not fallback if the rewrite path has an invalid endpoint. Meaning you can't fallback to `/users/` endpoint if the query path is an invalid endpoint.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the URL query anymore. I'm getting the 404 like you said. How do i make it as an "dynamic" endpoint?

Comment: Can you add the details of what you want to happen in your question? The answer will depend on those details. Right now it is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, so basically my JavaScript checks the URL query (for e.g. ?q=exampleuser) and makes an AJAX request to show details. I know that its possible in .htaccess to "rewrite" these url queries to make them look pretty. Thats what i want. So "/users.html?q=exampleuser" should be shown as "/users.html/exampleuser". (I have pretty URLS activated).But still recognize it as a URL query not a new .html site.

Comment: Still not following. Maybe edit your **question** body and show some examples of the flow you want to see. A rewrite path would not make a pretty url based on what you first asked. Now it seems you want to redirect (not rewrite) to the new path and have a SPA use the route as your query values.